# Persistent, binary data in a custom component

Tags: delphi, binary, components, streaming

I am making a custom component to hold binary data in a program.  What data type can hold and automatically stream binary data to a `.DFM` file?

I have tried `TBytes`, but it does not stream. `String` and `AnsiString` stream, but they are not good for binary data. I am trying to avoid using the manual `TReader`/`TWriter` approach.

Below is a little code piece that describes the problem.  The `BinProp` (`TBytes`) is not streamed into the `Blob.bin` file, even though the `BinProp` property is published:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  tBlob = class (TComponent)
  private
    fBinProp : TBytes;
    fString : String;
    procedure SetBinProp(const Value: TBytes);
    procedure SetStringProp(const Value: String);
  public
  published
    property BinProp : TBytes read fBinProp write SetBinProp;
    property StringProp : String read fString write SetStringProp;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure tBlob.SetBinProp(const Value: TBytes);
begin
  fBinProp := Value;
end;

procedure tBlob.SetStringProp(const Value: String);
begin
  fString := Value;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Blob : tBlob;
  i : integer;
  Fs : TFileStream;
begin
  Blob := tBlob.Create(Self);
  SetLength(Blob.fBinProp, 10);
  for I := 0 to 9 do
    Blob.BinProp[I] := i;
  Blob.StringProp := '1234567890';
  Fs := TFileStream.Create('Blob.bin', fmCreate);
  Fs.WriteComponent(Blob);
  Fs.Free;
  Blob.Free;
  Fs := TFileStream.Create('Blob.bin', fmOpenRead);
  Blob := Fs.ReadComponent(nil) as TBlob;
  Caption :=
    'Length BinProp: '+IntToStr(Length(Blob.BinProp))+    //0
    ' - Length StringProp: '+IntToStr(Length(Blob.StringProp))+ // 10
    ' - Value StringProp: '+Blob.StringProp;   // 1234567890
  Fs.free;
end;

initialization
  RegisterClass(tBlob);
end.
```

Comment: "*I am trying to avoid using the manual TReader/TWriter approach*" - why? That is the *correct* way to handle this situation.  There is no type that *automatically* streams binary data for you. You have to stream it yourself, and that means overriding `DefineProperties()`.

Comment: Ok! I thought that there maybe was some kind of a generic datatype that did the job for you, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

There is no data type that *automatically* streams binary data to/from a DFM.  You must stream the data manually. Have your component override the virtual [`DefineProperties()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TPersistent.DefineProperties) method, then it can call the [`TFiler.DefineBinaryProperty()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TFiler.DefineBinaryProperty) method to provide custom reader/writer methods that stream the binary data as needed.

See [Overriding the DefineProperties Method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overriding_the_DefineProperties_Method) in Embarcadero's DocWiki.

For example:

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  tBlob = class (TComponent)
  private
    fBinProp : TBytes;
    fString : String;
    procedure ReadBinProp(Stream: TStream);
    procedure WriteBinProp(Stream: TStream);
  protected
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
  public
  published
    property BinProp : TBytes read fBinProp write fBinProp;
    property StringProp : String read fString write fString;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure tBlob.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited DefineProperties(Filer);
  Filer.DefineBinaryProperty('BinPropBytes', ReadBinProp, WriteBinProp, Length(fBinProp) > 0);
end;

procedure tBlob.ReadBinProp(Stream: TStream);
var
  BinSize: Integer;
begin
  BinSize := Stream.Size;
  SetLength(fBinProp, BinSize);
  if BinSize > 0 then
    Stream.ReadBuffer(PByte(fBinProp)^, BinSize);
end;

procedure tBlob.WriteBinProp(Stream: TStream);
begin
  Stream.WriteBuffer(PByte(fBinProp)^, Length(fBinProp));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Blob : tBlob;
  I : Integer;
  Fs : TFileStream;
begin
  Blob := tBlob.Create(nil);
  try
    SetLength(Blob.fBinProp, 10);
    for I := 0 to 9 do
      Blob.BinProp[I] := Byte(i);
    Blob.StringProp := '1234567890';
    Fs := TFileStream.Create('Blob.bin', fmCreate);
    try
      Fs.WriteComponent(Blob);
    finally
      Fs.Free;
    end;
    FreeAndNil(Blob);
    Fs := TFileStream.Create('Blob.bin', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      Blob := Fs.ReadComponent(nil) as TBlob;
    finally
      Fs.Free;
    end;
    Caption :=
      'Length BinProp: '+IntToStr(Length(Blob.BinProp))+    //0
      ' - Length StringProp: '+IntToStr(Length(Blob.StringProp))+ // 10
      ' - Value StringProp: '+Blob.StringProp;   // 1234567890
  finally
    Blob.Free;
  end;
end;

initialization
  RegisterClass(tBlob);

end.
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the property wouldn't be visible in design-time in object inspector, because there's no property editor for `TBytes` either. There would still be a way to set it manually in DFM as hexadecimal string enclosed in curly braces. Custom property editor or component editor can do the job as well. Another option would be to remove `BinProp` from `published` section and introduce new published property that would encode the binary data as string; e.g: `property BinPropBase64: string read GetBinPropBase64 write SetBinPropBase64;`.

Comment: "*It's worth mentioning that the property wouldn't be visible in design-time in object inspector, because there's no property editor for TBytes either*" - a custom editor can be created if needed, though.  And being published does allow RTTI to be generated for the property, even if it is not being used for the DFM streaming.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Remy.
I posted a similar solution myself, but it was deleted by a "Moderator"...